# Why does the structure for cellular retinol binding protein show interactions with cadmium ions?

Tags: biochemistry, proteins, protein-structure, protein-binding, xray-crystallography

A structure of cellular retinol binding protein ([1CRB](http://www.ebi.ac.uk/thornton-srv/databases/cgi-bin/pdbsum/GetPage.pl?pdbcode=1crb)) contains two cadmium ions as ligands. Is Cd<sup>2+</sup> a ligand of CRBP and, if so, is that interaction necessary for protein function or is the protein a transporter to remove cadmium? My other thought is that the interaction only appears as a result of the methods the scientists used to determine the structure of the protein.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! We encourage you to do some research on your own and then, informed by what you have learned, ask any questions you still have (ideally with references to reliable sources). For example, your question about whether this is a cadmium transporter can be answered by looking at the entry for the structure you indicated! I also suspect that your last guess can be confirmed by looking at the linked paper. ——— Please also take the tour and then go through the help pages starting with How to Ask questions effectively on this site and edit your question accordingly. Thanks! 

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I am aware, there is no known requirement for Cd in mammalian systems, but it is extremely toxic ([Waalkes & Goering](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/tx00016a001)).

It would seem that cadmium is required to get crystals of RBP, and its presence is an artifact of the crystallization process ([ref](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1107/S0907444998002303)):

> Pig holoRBP crystals were obtained at 277 K by the sitting-drop vapor- diffusion method, at a final protein concentration of approximately 8 mg ml ~ and in the presence of 8%(v/v) 2-methyl-2,4- pentanediol, 3mM cadmium acetate, 0.1 M Tris-acetate, pH = 6.8

The only mammalian Cd-binding protein I am aware of is metallothione ([ref](https://pubs.acs.org/action/doSearch?field1=Contrib&text1=Michael+P.++Waalkes)), which was originally isolated as a Cd-binding protein ([ref](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja01574a064)), and allows safe transport of a highly toxic metal.

Carbonic anhydrase from the marine diatom *Thalassiosira weissflogi* can use Cd  as active-site metal (typically when Zn is low) and this may explain "the nutrient-like behaviour of cadmium in the ocean" [[ref](https://www.nature.com/articles/435042a) and [ref](https://www.nature.com/articles/nature06636)]

Comment: Also from the paper you quote: *"Cadmium ions represent an absolute requirement for the growth of orthorhombic crystals of... RBP"*